Config RGB in SoundBlaster AE-5 in Ubuntu)
I have a question, I just had a SoundBlaster AE-5 and it works without problems in Ubuntu but the question is with which program can I control the RGB of the AE-5 Sound Card in Ubuntu? Why is it not striking that I use the color red in Ubuntu and also when I restart from Ubuntu to Windows using audio, the audio cracks in Windows forcing me to turn it off to solve it
